# Agilent Vee or Matlab: 4 byte ASCII to floating point

Tags: matlab, ascii, precision

I currently have an instrument that sends 4 bytes representing a floating point number of 32-bit in little endian format, the data looks like:

```
Gz*=   
<«�=  
N×e=
```

or this

```
à|ƒ=
```

is there a conversion for this in matlab, Agilent vee and manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert an array of `char` to `single`, you can use [typecast](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html):

```
c = 'Gz*=';
f = typecast(c, 'single')

f =  0.041621
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implicitly!

```
    >> data = ['Gz*=';'<«�=';'N×e=']

data =

Gz*=
<«�=
N×e=
>> data+0

ans =

      71         122          42          61
      60         171       65533          61
      78         215         101          61
```

`data+0` forces it to be interpreted as a number which is fine.

If it's interpreted it backwards (I'm not sure if MATLAB is big or little endian) just use the [`swapbytes`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html) function.